# React Router Params not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I am trying to use params in my react redux application, but unfortunately its not working. I am getting a blank screen. Here is the code which i am following

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Router, Route, browserHistory} from 'react-router';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './rootReducer';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';

 const store = createStore(
 rootReducer,
 compose(
   applyMiddleware(thunk),
   window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f
 )
);
ReactDOM.render(
<Provider store={store}>
<Router history={browserHistory}>
  <Route path="/" component={Login}/>
  <Route path="/lists" component={requireAuth(Dashboard)}/>
  {/* Parameter route*/}
  <Route path="/record/:mEID" component={requireAuth(Record)}/>
</Router>
</Provider>,
document.getElementById('root')
);
```

When i go to my localhost url i.e. localhost:3000/record/16655 then i am getting error like this "http://localhost:3000/record/index.js is not found".

What could be the solution for this???

Here is my package.json for reference

```
 "lodash": "^4.17.4",
 "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
"react": "^15.1.0",
"react-bootstrap": "^0.31.0",
"react-bootstrap-table": "^3.3.7",
"react-dom": "^15.1.0",
"react-fontawesome": "^1.6.1",
"react-redux": "^4.4.5",
"react-router": "^3.0.2",
"redux": "^3.5.2",
"redux-thunk": "^2.1.0",
```

Comment: did you end up solving this?

Answer (score 0):

Try nesting your routes like this

```
...

<Route path='/record' ...>
  <Route path='/:meid' ../>
</Route>
```

Based on the [React-router tutorial#nested-routes](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/04-nested-routes)

```
<App>       {/*  /          */}
  <Repos>   {/*  /repos     */}
    <Repo/> {/*  /repos/123 */}
  </Repos>
</App>
```